# Working inside onDataChange method Android Firebase Database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from the Firebase database and then create an Array out of those items and create a Map with markers from that array List.

But when I try to run the Activity I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)'
on a null object reference
```

Here is my code. Please read comments for better understanding.

```
       mLocationDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                LocationCurrent post = dsp.getValue(LocationCurrent.class);
                Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(post.getLatitude());
                Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(post.getLongitude());
                currentLocationLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                latlngs.add(currentLocationLatLng);


                //Logging works fine I see all items of the latlngs array
                Log.i("LAT LONGS IN", String.valueOf(latlngs));

                //Same Exception points here
                for(int i = 0 ; i < latlngs.size() ; i++ ) {

                    createMarker(latlngs.get(i));
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
//Exception points here too
protected Marker createMarker(LatLng latlngmthd) {

    return mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlngmthd)
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
}
```

In my opinion I should work with data inside onDataChange method but map Object is not created there as you can see from the Exception. 
Moving onMapReady inside onDataChange is not allowed. So does anyone know any suggestions how could I create a map object and populate it with markers inside onDataChange method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `nMap` has not been initialized properly and is null.  The `onMapReady()` method you posted is empty.  That method is called when the map is ready to be used.  It should contain a statement to capture the map object.  You must also not add the listener until after the map is ready.  You could move it inside the same method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    nMap = googleMap;
    mLocationDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
}
```